# How to unit test javascript ES6 classes that encapsulate their own creation within a static function?

Tags: javascript, graphql

In Dan Schafer's React Europe talk (https://youtu.be/etax3aEe2dA?t=11m5s), he showed *one approach* to handling authorization in a GraphQL server could be delegating to a business logic layer in which each business object class has a [gen() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsdbM.png) that acts as the *"single source of truth"* for **both fetching and authorization**.

He implies that these classes could have no public constructor, thereby making gen() the only way to instantiate one of these classes.

As a C# dev, this wouldn't be [easily] unit-testable. Perhaps, I'm taking his example too literally.

In ES2015, is it possible to unit test the business logic in isolation with this pattern? If so, can you provide an example please?

---

Here's a related Q&A, but it doesn't address my question exactly:

Q: [With GraphQL, what is the benefit or necessity of declaring a backing model "class" that does not vary from the GraphQL "Type" in any obvious way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38160489/6439734)

A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38209996/6439734

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach I'd take would vary depending on what I was trying to test:

- If I was trying to unit test my authorization logic itself, I would almost certainly factor that logic out into something that looks like: [image: Code sample from slide from Dan Schafer React Europe 2016 Talk] Now I would just unit test `checkCanSee` completely on its own, passing in a fake `Viewer` object and fake data.
- If I was trying to unit test the logic in one of the instance methods of this class; say, if we had 
  `class TodoItem {
    getItemSummary() {
      return this.data.title + "(" + this.data.author.name + ")";
    }
  }`

  and I wanted to unit test that logic, there are a few options. In ES6, I'm not aware of an easy way to make the constructor actually private, so I could just call the constructor directly in my unit test with fake data. In another language, I'd hopefully be able to expose a method that was only visible by unit tests that would let me construct a new object with fake data. A third idea would be to extract out the unit test-worthy logic:
  `class TodoItem {
    getItemSummary() {
      return summarize(this.data.title, this.data.author.name);
    }
  }
  function summarize(title, name) {
    return title + "(" + name + ")";
  }`

  Now I could unit test `summarize` on its own.
- If I was trying to end-to-end test the whole class (which includes testing the `gen` function), I'd ideally have a way of setting up a shimmed instance of Redis; once I configured that shim with my fake data, I can just run the real `TodoItem.gen` and test the resulting object.
- If I wanted to unit test the implementation of `gen`, I'd probably need to use that same Redis shim above, and similarly install a fake version of `checkCanSee`, using something like https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html; from there, I could spy the call to Redis and to `checkCanSee` to make sure they are as expected, and test the various cases where Redis returns data/returns null or `checkCanSee` returns true/false.
- If I wanted to unit test code that consumes a `TodoItem` (say we have a function `renderTodoItem` that takes a `TodoItem` as an argument), I wouldn't use the real `TodoItem` implementation at all, I'd pass in a mock `TodoItem` to make sure that my unit test of `renderTodoItem` doesn't accidentally rely on implementation details of `TodoItem`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the information ... is it advisable to have a single source of truth of data fetching between internal and external users? given that both have different authorization logic ... and can see different things and perform different mutations